# How to get json array from request and use it in object using python with GAE?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

I'm learning python and exploring Google App Engine and I have faced this problem:

How to add json array that is within my json request, to ndb object?

Here is my model:

```
class Driver (ndb.Model):
    id = ndb.StringProperty()
    first_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    last_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    date_of_birth = ndb.StringProperty()
    phone_number = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    vehicles = ndb.StructuredProperty(Vehicle, repeated=False)
    document = ndb.StructuredProperty(Document, repeated=False)
    device_registration_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    time_created = ndb.TimeProperty()
    time_updated = ndb.TimeProperty()
    account_status = ndb.StringProperty()
    driver_status = ndb.StringProperty()


class Vehicle (ndb.Model):
    car_make = ndb.StringProperty()
    car_model = ndb.StringProperty()
    car_year = ndb.StringProperty()
    license_plate_number = ndb.StringProperty()


class Document (ndb.Model):
    driver_license = ndb.StringProperty()
    insurance_provider = ndb.StringProperty()
    insurance_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    insurance_expiration_date = ndb.StringProperty()
```

And my code for request handling looks like this:

```
class DriverManagementNew(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def post(self):
    jsonstring = self.request.body
    jsonobject = json.loads(jsonstring)
    driver_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    new_driver = Driver(
        id=driver_id,
        first_name=jsonobject["first_name"],
        last_name=jsonobject["last_name"],
        date_of_birth=jsonobject["date_of_birth"],
        phone_number=jsonobject["phone_number"],
        email=jsonobject["email"],
        vehicles=Vehicle(car_make=jsonobject["car_make"],
                         car_model=jsonobject["car_model"],
                         car_year=jsonobject["car_year"],
                         license_plate_number=jsonobject["license_plate_number"]),
        document=Document(driver_license=jsonobject["driver_license"],
                           insurance_provider=jsonobject["insurance_provider"],
                           insurance_id=jsonobject["insurance_id"],
                           insurance_expiration_date=jsonobject["insurance_expiration_date"]),
        device_registration_id=jsonobject["device_registration_id"],
        time_created=datetime.datetime.now(),
        time_updated=datetime.datetime.now(),
        account_status=jsonobject["account_status"],
        driver_status=jsonobject["driver_status"])
    new_driver.put()
```

I've had simpler model before, and i was not using StructuredProperty. My requests were working, but now when i send request like this:

```
{
  "first_name":"FName",
  "last_name":"LName",
  "date_of_birth":"01-02-1900",
  "phone_number":"+1123123123",
  "email":"test@test.com",
  "vehicles":{"car_make":"volkswagen",
            "car_model":"jetta",
            "car_year":"2000",
            "license_plate_number":"ABC01DC"
  },
  "document":{"driver_license":"F3377232G",
            "insurance_provider":"Geico",
            "insurance_id":"1433123aa",
            "insurance_expiration_date":"02-02-2018"
  },
  "device_registration_id":"id123123123123123",
  "account_status":"ACTIVATED",
  "driver_status":"ACTIVE"
}
```

I get **500 Server Error**

> NameError: name 'Vehicle' is not defined

I understand that this might be a very noob question, but I could not find an answer that would've worked for me. Can you please assist me?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like class Driver is referring to class Vehicle, but Vehicle hasn't been defined yet.  If you move the Vehicle definition up, it should get past this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem. Thanks to @dragonx for his comment, it helped me a lot.

My Handler:

```
class DriverManagementNew(webapp2.RequestHandler):


  def post(self):
    jsonstring = self.request.body
    jsonobject = json.loads(jsonstring)
    driver_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    vehicle = Vehicle(car_make=jsonobject["vehicles"]["car_make"],
                         car_model=jsonobject["vehicles"]["car_model"],
                         car_year=jsonobject["vehicles"]["car_year"],
                         license_plate_number=jsonobject["vehicles"]["license_plate_number"])
    doc = Document(driver_license=jsonobject["document"]["driver_license"],
                        insurance_provider=jsonobject["document"]["insurance_provider"],
                        insurance_id=jsonobject["document"]["insurance_id"],
                        insurance_expiration_date=jsonobject["document"]["insurance_expiration_date"])
    new_driver = Driver(
        id=driver_id,
        first_name=jsonobject["first_name"],
        last_name=jsonobject["last_name"],
        date_of_birth=jsonobject["date_of_birth"],
        phone_number=jsonobject["phone_number"],
        email=jsonobject["email"],
        vehicles=vehicle,
        document=doc,
        device_registration_id=jsonobject["device_registration_id"],
        time_created=datetime.datetime.now(),
        time_updated=datetime.datetime.now(),
        account_status=jsonobject["account_status"],
        driver_status=jsonobject["driver_status"])
    new_driver.put()
```

My model:

```
class Vehicle (ndb.Model):
    car_make = ndb.StringProperty()
    car_model = ndb.StringProperty()
    car_year = ndb.StringProperty()
    license_plate_number = ndb.StringProperty()


class Document (ndb.Model):
    driver_license = ndb.StringProperty()
    insurance_provider = ndb.StringProperty()
    insurance_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    insurance_expiration_date = ndb.StringProperty()


class Driver (ndb.Model):
    id = ndb.StringProperty()
    first_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    last_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    date_of_birth = ndb.StringProperty()
    phone_number = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    vehicles = ndb.StructuredProperty(Vehicle, repeated=False)
    document = ndb.StructuredProperty(Document, repeated=False)
    device_registration_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    time_created = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    time_updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    account_status = ndb.StringProperty()
    driver_status = ndb.StringProperty()
```